# Powershell - Need to pull all smtp addresses from ProxyAdresses for all users in an AD group into a single column

Tags: powershell

I have an AD group from which I need to pull all smtp addresses from ProxyAddresses for each user into a single column. I have the script below which is only pulling the first addresses from ProxyAddresses. Some users will have two or more addresses. What can I add to my script to pull all smtp addresses from ProxyAddresses. I'm new with Powershell have have struggled to get this to work. I've spent a good part of the day googling and just can't get there. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    <pre><Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "EDL_ProEquities Smarsh" -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Properties Proxyaddresses |  
    Select-Object @{ L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = {($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object 
    {$_ -like "*smtp:*"} | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'smtp:'}) -join 
    "`r`n'`;"}} |
    Export-CSV -Path "c:\temp\EDL.csv" -NoTypeInformation</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. ;-) I think you have at least two options to approach this task. Either you join all desired smtp addresses in one cell in your csv file like this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'EDL_ProEquities Smarsh' -Recursive |
Get-ADUser -Properties ProxyAddresses | 
ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        sAMAccountName = $_.sAMAccountName
        ProxyAddresses = ($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -match '^smtp:' } | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'smtp:' }) -join ','
    }
} |
Export-CSV -Path 'c:\temp\EDL.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

... or you output each individual smtp address on an individual line like this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'EDL_ProEquities Smarsh' -Recursive |
Get-ADUser -Properties ProxyAddresses |  
ForEach-Object {
    $User = $_
    $SMTPAddressList = $_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -match '^smtp:' } | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'smtp:' }
    foreach ($SMTPAddress in $SMTPAddressList) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            sAMAccountName = $User.sAMAccountName
            SMTPAddress    = $SMTPAddress 
        }
    }
} |
Export-CSV -Path 'c:\temp\EDL.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Olaf, thank you so much. My google searches weren't even close. Your second solution is exactly what I needed.